Как преобразовать дату типа String в формате "dd.mm.yyyy" в дату типа datetime utc?
Как конвертировать дату типа String в формате "dd.mm.yyyy" в дату типа datetime utc?
Например, дату типа String в формате "2024-11-06 14:42:49.374459409 UTC" могу конвертировать в дату типа datetime utc, так: data.parse().unwrap();
use chrono::{Utc, DateTime};

fn main() {
    let now = Utc::now();
    let data_string: String = format!("{}", now);
    println!("data_string = {:?}", data_string);

    let data_datetime_utc: DateTime<Utc> = 
    data_string.parse().unwrap();

    println!("data_datetime_utc = {:?}", data_datetime_utc);
}

/* 
   data_string = "2024-11-06 15:01:35.027142096 UTC"
   data_datetime_utc = 2024-11-06T15:01:35.027142096Z
*/

play...
Вот я ввожу в терминале через use std::io; дату в формате, например, "03.11.2024" или получаю в переменную: let data: String = "03.11.2024".to_string();, а перевести в datetime utc не получается.
получилось типа такого...

@Dmitry, спасибо

+1 вам за отзывчиваость, да и вопрос по делу)

В той же документации chrono вроде есть пример парсинга строки произвольного формата chrono::NaiveDate::parse_from_str("03.11.2024", "%d.%m.%Y")

@andreymal, да Ваш вариант походу правильный, спасибо. Думал, что типы DateTime<Utc> и NaiveDate принципиально разные, но нужные мне действия с NaiveDate в дальнейшем получились. Отмечу как правильный. (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f8652f12bdd778cc56cfcaabe381898a)
